# My code works but need an elegant way to produce sub-lists out of a list

Tags: python, list, loops, split, nested-loops

As below, I have a list called `lst` of 2 elements that represent some slot indices for me. I want obtain sub-lists from this that are produced based on the value of `slotss` as below.

```
lst=[0,10]
slotss=4
out_lst= [0,3],[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[4,7],[5,8],[6,9] (but not 7,10)
```

**My below code works but I need an elegant way of doing this.** Because the profiler shows that the code spends more time in the above task.

```
out_lst=[]
    for u in range(len(lst)):        
                    
        condi1=lst[u][0]
        condi2=lst[u][1]

        break_signal=0
        cnt2=condi1
        cnt1=condi1
        for i in range(condi2+1):
            in_lst=[]
    
            if i!=0:
                cnt2=cnt2+1
            
            for j in range(2):
                if cnt1>=condi2:
                    break_signal=1
                    break
                else:
                    in_lst.append(cnt1)
                    cnt1=cnt1+slotss-1
                    
            
            if break_signal==1:
                break
            else:
                cnt1=cnt2+1
        
            out_lst.append(in_lst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write a list comprehension to achieve the result you want:

```py
lst = [0, 10]
slotss = 4

out_lst = [[start, start + (slotss - 1)] for start in range(lst[0], lst[1] - (slotss - 1))]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [5, 8], [6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this expression more concise using `tuple()` and a generator expression:

```py
[start, end] = [0, 10]
size = 4

tuple([i, i + size - 1] for i in range(start, end - size + 1))
```

This outputs:

```py
([0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8], [5, 9])
```

Comment: start and end can be variables outside a list in this case: `start, end  = 0, 10`

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```py
out = list(enumerate(range(slotss - 1, lst[1]), lst[0]))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: This looks awesome :) you can avoid the additional list by doing `out = [*enumerate(range(slotss - 1, lst[1]), lst[0])]`

Comment: @FabioCraigWimmerFlorey Andrej's version does not create any more lists than your version does, but is considered more Pythonic for being more readable.